# JSF button to reset the session

Tags: jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, java-ee-5

Is there a way to reset (clear) the session for a user, when he clicks on a button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about

```
session.invalidate();
```

> invalidate method of session object is
>   used to discard the session and
>   releases any objects stored as
>   attributes. This method helps to
>   reduce memory overhead and achieves
>   improvement in performance. It is
>   always a good practice to explicitly
>   remove or invalidate sessions using
>   session.invalidate() method.

or

```
session.removeAttribute(String)
```

> The removeAttribute method of session
>   object is used to remove the attribute
>   and value from the session.